# Room: error: There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: abc)

Tags: android, database, android-room

I'd like to use the same kind of object to query multiple tables. I defined a base class like below:

```
@Entity
public class BaseWordId {
    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    public Integer word_id;
}
```

I then subclassed the base class and also defined DAO for each of them.

```
@Entity(tableName = "abc")
public class ABC extends BaseWordId {
}

@Entity(tableName = "xyz")
public class XYZ extends BaseWordId {
}

@Dao
public interface ABCDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM abc")
    List<ABC> get_all();
}

@Dao
public interface XYZDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM xyz")
    List<XYZ> get_all();
}
```

But I kept getting a compile error that no such table: abc and no such table: xyz. Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when trying to use Room library. \[SQLITE\_ERROR\] SQL error or missing database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45170399/error-when-trying-to-use-room-library-sqlite-error-sql-error-or-missing-datab)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You should mention **both** the `entities` in your roomDatabase class.

```
@Database(entities = {BaseWordId.class, ABC.class}, version = VERSION_CODE, exportSchema = false) 
public abstract class YourDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    //your Daos
}
```